# Do native speakers use this construction with numbers?

Tags: numbers, countability

We often say something like "a million and two hundred dollars" or "ten thousand and fifty five dollars", which are the common ways to say such things. However, I remember a certain form, which is the inversed way I once spotted that interests me:

- Ten hundred and two thousand dollars.
- Seventy eight and a hundred bucks.
- A thousand and half a million pounds.

And also these two forms:

- One hundred dollars and two thousand more.
- A hundred over a thousand coins.

Comment: They read like arithmetic exercises, and the last two only make sense as such. Sometimes I might say "twelve hundred" but I won't complicate it by then adding more parts. I never start with the smallest section, but the largest.

Comment: Tangentially, "ten hundred" is not idiomatic to me - I would always say "one thousand."

Comment: Who says "a million and two hundred dollars"? Is that 100,000,002 x 100 dollars or 1,000,000 + 200 dollars? Here in New England people say "One million two hundred dollars". With the exception of "A thousand and a half million pounds" which sound like plausible way to avoid the billion/milliard confusion, your other examples do indeed sound like math puzzles. Why else would anyone say "Ten hundred and two thousand dollars" instead of simply "three thousand dollars"?

Comment: *I remember a certain form, which is the inverted way I once spotted that interests me:* You are perhaps thinking of an old-fashioned method of counting in English for numbers between 20 and 99. 25 can be said as "Twenty-five" or "five and twenty". Likewise, 73 can be said as seventy-three and "three and seventy". The second versions of these are archaic: the only current use I can think of in British English is "five and twenty", which is sometimes used when telling the time: **A** What time is it?" **B** It is five and twenty to six." (= 05:35, i.e. 25 minutes before 6 o'clock.)

Comment: Related (seeing as that feature is still broken): [Why are two-digit numbers in Jonathan Swift's “Gulliver's Travels” (1726) written in “German style”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/494694/why-are-two-digit-numbers-in-jonathan-swifts-gullivers-travels-1726-writte)

Comment: For dates twelve hundred is quite common. The Magna Carta was signed in 1215, twelve hundred and fifteen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In modern English, we give the largest amounts first and then work down. "Ten thousand three hundred eight-five", NOT "eighty-five, three hundred, and ten thousand".

I have seen the smaller numbers given first in old books. Hundreds of years ago apparently English-speakers did say things like "six and twenty". But that's just about non-existent today. You might see it in poetry where someone is trying to make a particular rhyme or rhythm.

"One hundred dollars and two thousand more" ... I can't imagine someone writing that except to be deliberate strange-sounding, or as I say to make a rhyme in a poem, or something of that sort.

Comment: I might say "I'll pay you two hundred dollars today and two thousand more over the next twelve months", but that wouldn't be a single number.

Comment: @gnasher729 Sure. I can think of any number of sentences like that, where it's two or more different numbers.